# Change autocomplete selected item programmatically in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am not advance in Vue, suppose we have :

```
<v-autocomplete v-model="defaultUser"
                :hint="`User: ${defaultUser.username}`"
                :items="users"
                :item-text="item =>`${item.firstName} - ${item.lastName}`"
                item-value="userId"
                label="Related user"
                persistent-hint
                return-object
                dense
                single-line outlined 
                :filter="userFilter"></v-autocomplete>
```

and `data` :

```
data: () => ({
    users: [],
    defaultUser: { userId: 0, username: 'select user', firstName: '', lastName: '' },
    .....
```

by below snipped code nothing happened in UI, in the other words I want to change the selected item by code but nothing happened:

```
axios.get('api/user/relatedusers')
    .then(response => { 
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.id !== 0) { 
            this.defaultUser.userId = response.data.relatedId;//Here is nothing happened 
        } 

    }).catch(err => { 
    });
```

why this does not work if every variables are under Vue control, I mean bind and observable.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" – how? Are you sure that line of code is being executed? All you're doing is changing the user ID of `defaultUser` instead of changing the entire `defaultUser` object; this might explain why the autocomplete component isn't updating correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should find a user by id and then assign him to this.defaultUser:

```
this.defaultUser = this.users.find(x => x.userId === response.data.relatedId)
```